# Win Error 5 has occurred when I tried to execute Pytorch code

Tags: anaconda, operating-system, pytorch

I'm new to Anaconda. I tried to execute Pytorch Adversarial Neural Network in anaconda. It shows some error that I have no clue. Here is the code that downloads dataset

```py
# MNIST Test dataset and dataloader declaration
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.MNIST('../data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),])),batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
```

This is the error message I got :

```
     PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-4-59310f6a37f8> in <module>
 41 
 42 # MNIST Test dataset and dataloader declaration
 43 test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.MNIST('../data', train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),])),batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
 44 
 45 # Define what device we are using

     ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py in __init__(self, root, 
     train, 
 transform, target_transform, download)
 77 
 78         if download:
 79             self.download()
 80 
 81         if not self._check_exists():

        ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py in download(self)
138             return
139 
140         os.makedirs(self.raw_folder, exist_ok=True)
141         os.makedirs(self.processed_folder, exist_ok=True)
142 

     ~\anaconda3\lib\os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
211     if head and tail and not path.exists(head):
212         try:
213             makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
214         except FileExistsError:
215             # Defeats race condition when another thread created the path

      ~\anaconda3\lib\os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
211     if head and tail and not path.exists(head):
212         try:
213             makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
214         except FileExistsError:
215             # Defeats race condition when another thread created the path

    ~\anaconda3\lib\os.py in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
221             return
222     try:
223         mkdir(name, mode)
224     except OSError:
225         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '../data' .
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the `'../data'` to another directory, like `'/Users/***/Downloads/data'` or somewhere else.